# Extract a string containing () and populate a list of the words in the ()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have several columns in a dataframe, of which am working on one specific column and a sample subset of rows has been shown below.
I would like to create a list of all the roles in the column.

So if the dataframe column looks like below,

```
**Roles**
Bad Good (UK) Plc (Lead actor)
CQWR Luxembourg SA [BIL] (actor, Producer)
YZ PQR Ltd (Sponsor)
ABCDSA (Actress, Sponsor, Producer, Writer)
```

Then the list should be unique roles seen in the entire dataframe.

```
[Lead actor, actor, Producer, Sponsor, Actress, Writer]
```

So the splitting is essentially happening from the right side, and on the opening parenthesis.
and then i'll have to ensure the list is unique

Answer (score 1):

```
values = df["Roles"].tolist()

new_dict = {}
for el in values:
    el = el.rsplit("(", 1)[-1].strip(")")
    for el2 in el.split(", "):
        new_dict[el2] = 1

unique_list = list(new_dict.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am assuming that we are considering the values which are only in the last column.

```py
rows = [
    "Bad Good (UK) Plc (Lead actor)",
    "CQWR Luxembourg SA [BIL] (actor, Producer)",
    "YZ PQR Ltd (Sponsor)",
    "ABCDSA (Actress, Sponsor, Producer, Writer)"
    ]

uniqueRoles = []
seenRoles = set()

for row in rows:

    roles = row.rsplit("(")[-1].rsplit(")")[0]
    eachRoles = roles.split(", ")

    for role in eachRoles:
        if not role in seenRoles:
            uniqueRoles.append(role)
            seenRoles.add(role)

print(uniqueRoles)
```

Output :

```
['Lead actor', 'actor', 'Producer', 'Sponsor', 'Actress', 'Writer']
```